# Style Modal.method() Ant Design with Styled Component

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

I'm trying some way to style the following methods of the Ant Design modal:

- Modal.info
- Modal.warning
- Modal.success
- Modal.error

The default component was styled normally with the following property:

```
const StyledModal = styled(ModalAntd)`
  & .ant-btn-default {
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.color.neutral[400]};
    color: ${props => props.theme.color.neutral[100]};
    border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.color.neutral[400]};
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
  }

  & .ant-btn-primary {
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.color.brand.primary};
    color: ${props => props.theme.color.neutral[100]};
    border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.color.brand.primary};
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
  }

  & .ant-modal-body {
    color: ${props => props.theme.color.neutral[500]};
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  & .ant-modal-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: ${props => props.theme.color.neutral[1000]};
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  & .ant-modal-confirm-info {
    background-color: red;
  }
`;
```

and is being returned in the following format:

```
function AlertModals({ title, visible, onOk, onCancel, children, ...props }) {
  return(
    <StyledModal {...props} okText="Sim" cancelText="Não" title={title} visible={visible} onOk={onOk} onCancel={onCancel}>
    {children}
    </StyledModal>
  )
};
```

but the problem is when i am trying to use the methods i need they are not being affected by styling

```
function Info({title, content}) {
  styledInfo.info({
    title,
    content,
  })
};  

function Warning({title, content}) {
  StyledModal.warning({
    title,
    content,
  })
};

function Success({title, content}) {
  StyledModal.success({
    title,
    content,
  })
};

function Error({title, content}) {
  StyledModal.error({
    title,
    content,
  })
};

AlertModals.Warning = Warning;
AlertModals.Success = Success;
AlertModals.Error = Error;
AlertModals.Info = Info;

export default AlertModals;
```

Summing up my question, how can I style methods, since methods are a function and not a component that I can style with styled components

Comment: I think firstly, you need to make your functions have `return` properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today, I only managed to solve it by styling directly using globalStyles from styled-components, I'll give you an example of what I changed, I hope it helps you.

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'
import breakpoints from '../../theme/breakpoints'

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  @media(max-width: ${breakpoints.TABLET_MEDIUM}px) {
    .ant-modal-confirm-btns {
      display: flex;
    }
    .ant-modal-confirm-btns button{
      width:100%;
    }
  }

  @media(max-width: ${breakpoints.MOBILE_LARGE}px){
    .ant-modal-confirm-btns {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .ant-modal-confirm .ant-modal-confirm-btns .ant-btn + .ant-btn{
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
`

export default GlobalStyle
```